# Using an process to run AppleScript codes with Arguments in Swift

Tags: swift, applescript

To run AppleScript using processes in Swift is needed something like this

```swift
let process = Process()
if process.isRunning == false {
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
    process.arguments = ["/Users/user/Documents/activateApplication.scpt"]
    process.standardError = pipe
    process.launch()
}
```

but how, using processes I can send more arguments? like "Safari" and use this arguments in the destination script?

the activateApplication.scpt is:

```
on run appName
    tell application appName to activate
end run
```

Comment: As you write, arguments guy takes an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in the `osascript` man page.  Pass the script arguments as additional arguments after the script file, and they will appear as a list in the first (and only) argument of your `run` handler.  Your Swift code would look something like this:

```
    process.arguments = ["/Users/user/Documents/activateApplication.scpt", "Safari"]
```

...and your script would look like this:

```
on run argv
    tell app (item 1 of argv) to activate
end
```